# Combine list of vectors with same beginning

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

There is a multitude of vectors all starting alike:

```
item_4
item_5
item_17 
..
.
```

How can one combine them all at once by using the "item_" part?

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the meaning of combining here, give an example and expected outcome, so that people can help.

Comment: looking for an alternative to
items_all <- c(item_4, item_5, item_17, ....)

Comment: I am not sure, but this may help you: `unname(unlist(mget(grep('^item_', ls(), value=TRUE), envir = .GlobalEnv)))`, I am assuming here that item_4, item_5, item_17 contains some values(It is not clear from your question)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this all `item_` objects:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  assign(paste('item_',i,sep = ''), c(4,5,5,56,i))
}
```

You can find them and combine them with this methods

```
all = c()
for( i in grep('item_',objects())){
  all = c(all, get(objects()[i]))
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for